# What is the autocorrelation of a Dirac pulse?

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals, autocorrelation, pulse

What is the autocorrelation of $x(t) = \delta(t)$?

Can you explain to me how to calculate it?

Comment: Related: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/43174/21075

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/48067/91764

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/12944/339790

Comment: mathematicians and electrical engineers usually look at $\delta(t)$ differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, by definition of the $\delta$ distribution, you have:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) \delta(t-T)\, \textrm{d}t = f(T)$

The autocorrelation of a function $g(t)$ can be computed via:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g^{*}(t)g(t + \tau)\, \textrm{d}t$, with $g^*$ as the complex conjugate of $g$. Since $\delta(t)$ is real-valued, this is conjugation can be skipped. So you are left with:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta^{*}(t)\delta(t + \tau)\, \textrm{d}t = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t)\delta(t + \tau)\, \textrm{d}t = \delta(-\tau)$.

The first = sign comes from the autocorrelation of the real-valued $\delta$, the second from the definition of the $\delta$-distribution.

So, the autocorrelation function of the $\delta$-distribution is the distribution itself. A eigenfunction of the autocorrelation function, so to say ;)

Think about it, this does make sense: the only perfect match is achieved with no time shift, ie at $\tau = 0$. All other shifts would end up with one of the arguments of the $\delta$ being different from 0, hence with the $\delta$-function being 0 there.

BTW: $\delta(-\tau) = \delta(\tau)$, since the function/distribution is symmetric.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: I am not sure mathematicians would agree.

Comment: At first, I was in line with your comment, but apparently this can be well defined

Comment: The first equation $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\delta(t-T)dt = f(T)$$ is valid only when $f(t)$ is an ordinary function that is continuous at $t=T$. So, applying this to conclude that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(t)\delta(t+\tau)dt = \delta(-\tau)$$ is not very convincing.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I fear you are right.

Comment: While your result is correct, the method of obtaining it isn't. You can easily fix it by taking the argument to the frequency domain.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac Sadly, I cannot delete an accepted answer. Maybe you would like to elaborate on that in an additional answer, which then can hopefully be upvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at documents like  [Lecture notes on Distributions](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~hasse/distributioner_eng.pdf), Hasse Carlsson, or [Convolution dans l'espace $\mathcal{D}'_+(\mathbb{R})$](http://www.uvt.rnu.tn/resources-uvt/cours/Distribution/convolution/Chapitre-1/index.html), convolution of distributions can be defined under some technical conditions. However, when one of the operand has a compact support, as $\delta(t)$ does, the convolution is well-defined. From [Wikipedia:Distribution-Convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Convolution):

> **Distribution of compact support**: It is also possible to define the
>   convolution of two distributions S and T on $\mathbb{R}^n$, provided one of them
>   has compact support.

If you prefer classical books, there is: [Francois Trèves, Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions and Kernels](https://www.abebooks.com/9780486453521/Topological-Vector-Spaces-Distributions-Kernels-0486453529/plp), 1967:

[image: Francois Treves, Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions and Kernels]

Adding that $\delta(t)$  is the neutral element, then $\delta(t)$ is its own autocorrelation.

This lazy version avoids to write cumbersome Dirac products under integral signs. Nota: I do admit that I initially thought it was way less simple.

Comment: We do get into trouble for $\tau=0$ though, don't we?

Comment: Intuitively yes, but the standard distribution theory seems to be OK with that. While the square of a Dirac is not defined.

Comment: But for $\tau=0$ we get exactly that, the square of the Dirac impulse, which is indeed undefined, with or without integral, as far as I know.

Comment: As far as I remember, operations on distributions are defined with respect to integration over a set of test functions. Don't mean to convince your with an analogy, yet it's a bit (more complicated) like the [Cauchy principal value (a distribution)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Well-definedness_as_a_distribution), which can get sense  over Schwartz functions

Comment: Would you care to write a fuller explanation of how you came to change your mind from [two years ago](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/43176/235) when you wrote that $(\delta(t))^2$ is undefined?

Comment: I really think I did not change my mind: $\delta^2(t)$ is (to me as a DSP guy) ill-defined for my purposes (or beyond my reach), but $\delta(t)\ast \delta(t)$ is OK (to me today), but remember this is only a shorthand notation for a linear operation over smooth dense function spaces.